# How to combine two neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, caffe

sorry,the title may be confusing,

the thing is , I have trained two network.

one is to classify the gender of gorilla

another one is to  classify the gender of human

Then,I want to train another network to classify the gender of primate animals.

**So, how can I make up a new network from those two existed networks?**

because as we know,human and gorilla are one kind of primate animals.

this new network must know further semantic meaning of gender based on those two existed networks

is it fine that just simply input gorilla data and human data to train this new network? or it is a dumb way?

Thank you, any response is good for newbie :)

Comment: If you don't have any other data then simply using the human+gorilla data to train the new classifier is a good starting point, because it's the easiest thing to do. If you have other unlabelled data (other primates which are not human or gorilla), you could look for methods from domain-adaptation or transfer learning. The idea is that unlabelled data can help a classifier to perform better on samples from a different distribution (that is, different from the one used in training)

Comment: Have you thought about Siamese networks?

Comment: I don't really know  Siamese networks,thank you for giving me this keyword,I 'll google it

Answer (score 0):

Since both human and gorilla are primates, their data is suitable for the training of a network for classifying genders of primates. However, as mentioned at http://neuralnetworksanddeeplearning.com too much similar data may lead to low prediction rates for other data.